# Sync html element's text with Raphael paper.print()

Tags: javascript, fonts, raphael, css

I am trying to create editor which will create pixel perfect copy of text by using paths. To create SVG paths I use Raphael.js [print](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.print) method. The problem is I can't understand how to setup `print` function to make it exactly like text in html element(i.e span).

Here is example of `print` call:

```
var textPath = _r.print(0, 0, 'Default text', font1Cufon, 16, 'baseline', 0);
```

and i.e I have such span:

```
<span class="text">Default text</span>
```

css:

```
.text {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-family: 'font1';
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

It is not product code but I think the main idea is clear. It almost work but there is some offset between two types of text. Is anybody have idea how sync them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you don't have full control over the font rendering engine used by the HTML text rendering process in the same way you do with the SVG path rendering. Among other things, there can be subtle differences in letter-spacing, kerning, anti-aliasing, sub-pixel anti-aliasing, and even specific font-family glyph choices not just across operating systems, but even browsers.

In general, this is all for the best: fonts in browsers are usually designed to be consistent with overall font display choices at the operating system level. I appreciate that it makes what you want to do pretty hard. If you have something almost working and you can control for browser/OS/font settings, one option is to manually position each and every letter, as is done in [lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com/).

Comment: Sad but true: system/browser font rendering is subtly but inevitably idiosyncratic.  Good answer.

Comment: @Plynx, thank you for answer and what do you think how is it possible to make not pixel-perfect but close to that? Or it will be solution only for one font/browser/device?

Comment: @RubenNagoga Close to pixel perfect is kind of hard to quantify—I'm sure there are any number of ways to get you almost there, but yeah, it will probably not be cross-browser/cross device. Heck, even the fonts aren't the same on every device—they might be substituting something different from your Cufon font. You might think about using Canvas-by writing text to Canvas you can read the individual pixels off with Javascript. Also, if you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates what's going wrong, I might be able to fix something obvious that might be overlooked.